# Runtime Exception when using espresso and simulating onClick action on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using espresso for instrumentation testing. When I am write for click on recyclerview item at position it is failing with an exception.
I am attching stacktrace of the exception.

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

I am using above code for click. Also I tried to give a sleep time of 2000 miliseconds before the click to avoid this crash but that too is not working.

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'actionOnItemAtPosition performing ViewAction: single click on item at position: 0' on view 'with id: com.demotech.demo:id/recycler_view'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:85)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:57)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:316)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:177)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:118)
at com.demotech.demo.activities.HomeActivityTest.scrollToItemBelowFold_checkItsText(HomeActivityTest.java:76)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1967)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is assignable from class: class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131230763, res-name=call_log_recycler_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=840, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@828148, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=84.0, child-count=8}"
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:64)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:157)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
```

My main aim is to first click on the `recyclerview` item then then one childview of that itemview will be visible then I will click at a view present in that childview.

following is code inside view holder which I am using to linsten click on recyclerview item.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"inside on click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();

                    if (!itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false)) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"inside on click - if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        expandedViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, true);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"inside on click - else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        expandedViewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

`itemView` is defined inside ViewHolder class

```
 public abstract static class ViewHolder {
        @NonNull
        public final View itemView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of your stack trace you can find this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is assignable from class: class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131230763, res-name=call_log_recycler_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=840, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@828148, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=84.0, child-count=8}"
```

I think the `RecyclerView` is not `visible` at the time of your action.

Comment: it is visible, in the logs also you can see visibility=VISIBLE, width=540, height=840 and also I have observed this too, it is visible before clicking

Comment: It says it is a constraint. It is failed to meet. It should be visible but maybe it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the error.
I was using `com.android.support` for recyclerview

And `androidx.test.espresso:espresso` for espresso.

And so there was this error due to compatibility issue.

I changed the `com.android.support` to `androidx`(`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`) for recyclerview too and for other components also.